# Баланс клиентов МойСклад

Tags: мойсклад-api

Требуется обмен данными денежного баланса контрагентов Интернет-магазин <-> МойСклад, для фиксирования факта оплаты через интернет-магазин с карты либо для фиксирования оплаты через функционал "Розница".

Смотрю API Мой Склад https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html , и не вижу способа подтянуть все проводки по балансу клиентов.

Если вы знаете такой способ - подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обмен данными денежного баланса контрагента Интернет-Магазина и МойСклад не производится, но его можно реализовать под себя. В документации есть [метод](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), там выводится баланс Контрагента.

Comment: Этот метод выводит только конечный баланс контрагента и все, детализации какой то нет.

Смысл в том что бы фиксировать оплату заказов, так же возможна ситуация с предоплатой, когда сумма заказа меньше чем сумма оплаты. Поэтому важно знать не только конечный баланс

Comment: Вывода промежуточного баланса или детализации нет. Если вас интересуют именно заказы по конкретному кантрагенту , то для этого есть отдельный [метод АПИ](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)